# How to fetch complete objects (not faults) from CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm new to CoreData concept, and may be I'm getting something wrongly, but I want to fetch fully-qualified array of data from CoreData (not these abstract faults).

My problem is that I displaying a list of objects from CoreData to user in UITableView and at the same time refreshing data in background thread. If user is scrolling TableView at the same time as some of objects were deleted/changed I'm getting `CoreData could not fulfill a fault` exception

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, it is actually easy, need to set request's property `ReturnsObjectsAsFaults` to `NO`

like this:

```
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

I'ts strange nobody answered this simple question